# nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble downloading the html file form a url. It seems that the html file should be getting stored in the code but the webview won't display it. i keep getting a 
nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color message in the logcat.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


WebView display;
Button goButton;
//Message msg;
EditText urlEditText;
Handler showContent = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

        display.loadData((String) msg.obj, "text/html", "UTF-8");

        return false;
    }
});
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     display = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    urlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlText);
    goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);

    goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Thread thread = new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                URL url2 = null;

                        try {
                            //url2 = new URL(urlEditText.getText().toString());
                            url2 = new URL("http://www.google.com");

                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url2.openStream()));


                            String reply = " ", tempReply = " ";

                            tempReply = reader.readLine();
                            while (tempReply != null){
                                reply = reply + tempReply;
                                tempReply = reader.readLine();
                            }

                            Message msg = Message.obtain();
                            msg.obj = reply;

                            showContent.sendMessage(msg);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
  }
};
     thread.start();

        }
    });


}
```